# Oracle error PLS-00103

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I am trying to provide a string parameter on stored procedure that generates a dynamic query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure FMIS3.dynamic_pivot(p_cursor in out sys_refcursor, FISCAL_YEAR in FMS_K_BUDGET_ALLOCATION_MST.FKBAM_FISCAL_YEAR%type)
as
sql_query varchar2(5000) := 'select FKOM_OFFICE_ID,FKBAM_BUDGET_ID ';
begin
    for x in (select distinct PFS_SOURCE_ID,PFS_SOURCE_ENG from PBS_FC_SOURCE WHERE PFS_UPPER_SOURCE_ID!=0 )
    loop
        sql_query := sql_query ||
            ' , sum(case when FKBAB_SOURCE_ID = '||x.PFS_SOURCE_ID||' then FKOD_AMOUNT ELSE 0 end) as '||x.PFS_SOURCE_ENG;
            dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);
    end loop;
    sql_query := sql_query || ' FROM FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_DTL
    JOIN FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_MST ON FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_MST.FKOM_OFFICE_MST_ID=FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_DTL.FKOD_OFFICE_MST_ID
    JOIN FMS_K_BUDGET_ALLOCATION_DTL ON FMS_K_BUDGET_ALLOCATION_DTL.FKBAD_BUDGET_ALLOC_DTL_ID=FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_DTL.FKOD_BUDGET_ALLOC_AD_ID
    JOIN FMS_K_BUDGET_ALLOCATION_MST ON FMS_K_BUDGET_ALLOCATION_MST.FKBAM_BUDGET_ALLOC_ID=FMS_K_BUDGET_ALLOCATION_DTL.FKBAB_BUDGET_ALLOC_ID
    JOIN PBS_FC_BUDGET ON PBS_FC_BUDGET.PFB_BUDGET_ID=FMS_K_BUDGET_ALLOCATION_MST.FKBAM_BUDGET_ID
    WHERE FKBAM_FISCAL_YEAR='||FISCAL_YEAR||'
    GROUP BY FKOM_OFFICE_ID,FKBAM_BUDGET_ID ';
    dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);    
    open p_cursor for sql_query;    
end;
```

You can see I am using the value from parameter as condition as

```
WHERE FKBAM_FISCAL_YEAR='||FISCAL_YEAR||'
```

but this gives me error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
null pragma raise return select update while with
<an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
<a bind variable> << close current delete fetch lock insert
open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge
pipe
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I don't get the syntax error when compiling this.

Comment: @Chris : you can see the error now ...

Comment: Seems you have a line break within the string constant (hard to see if your editor wraps lines).

Comment: I removed that break, the error seems gone but its not returning results for true condition

Comment: "its not returning results for true condition" - and what precisely do you expect us to do about that?  You have the data, you have the results, you understand the business rules.  We're not telepathic, we can't debug your implementation remotely.

Comment: Its not returning results for true condition means there is something fault on something I have changed as per @Chris mentioned. And yeah, there was something missing, I have debugged it myself. And I am not expecting someone to debug this remotely but I was needing help from people who wish to help.

Comment: @Chris : thanks, it worked as I made following changes. See added answer. Anyway, thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed:

```
WHERE FKBAM_FISCAL_YEAR='||FISCAL_YEAR||'
GROUP BY FKOM_OFFICE_ID,FKBAM_BUDGET_ID ';
```

to

```
WHERE FKBAM_FISCAL_YEAR='''||FISCAL_YEAR||''' GROUP BY FKOM_OFFICE_ID,FKBAM_BUDGET_ID ';
```

Answer (score 1):

if `FISCAL_YEAR` is a varchar2 as you say, then it needs puttng in quotes. Better still, use a bind variable here. i.e.

```
 WHERE FKBAM_FISCAL_YEAR=:year
    GROUP BY FKOM_OFFICE_ID,FKBAM_BUDGET_ID ';
open p_cursor for sql_query using fiscal_year;
```

if this is still failing, show us the output of  the line

```
dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);
```

i also assume `PFS_SOURCE_ID` is a number, and `PFS_SOURCE_ENG` is a string with no spaces/or reserved words in the rows.

Comment: output ??? if you are asking the generated query, give me idea how to do that ...

Comment: @hsuk ignore that, i see its on compilation. if you save it to a .sql file and run it in using SQL*PLus instead of the GUI (Is that pl/sql developer?) do you get the same error? as it compiles ok for me here

Comment: its not SQL*Plus, its Toad